# Compile Java to a Javascript Library Using GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, compilation

In my project I need to take Java code and compile it to a Javascript library so it may be used in my web application.
I'm thinking of using GWT, but I don't need all that it offers. I just need a simple command line utility that can take Java code and emit Javascript.
I haven't used GWT before and I'm getting a little lost in all of the information out there about building a complete web application.
The [GWT Exporter](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/) project seems interesting, but I can't figure out how to use in my use case.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: A "complete" GWT web application may consist of a single entry point class which compiles into a single JavaScript file. So, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not a GWT expert and it seems too complicated for my use case. A simple command line utility that works like: "compile-java-to-js JavaFile.java" would be ideal for me.

Answer (score 1):

[ST-JS](http://st-js.github.io/) may be what you're looking for. In a nutshell, it's a way to compile a subset of Java into JavaScript so your Java and JavaScript code use the same API. The Java side of the tool even emulates jQuery (so you can use `$(...)` in Java code with code completion and type safety).

This code can't be executed in the Java VM. It's mainly a type safe way to write JavaScript code.

You can find more details in my blog post: http://blog.pdark.de/2013/10/24/jazoon-2013-stjs-managing-javascript-application-complexity/